# mysql-server-5.5 has unmet dependencies

Tags: dependencies

Every time I open the software center I get this message:

```
Item can not be installed or removed until package catalog is repaired
```

I click repair then I get

```
Package operation failed
```

I tried to remove `mysql-server-5.5` using terminal `sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server-5.5` and I got this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed"
```

I got the same message when tried to install it. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

Edit: I tried: `sudo apt-get remove mysql-sever` and I got this:

```
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure): 
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Update 2: the system has sent me a message that this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/1311925):

Comment: Do you really want to remove MySQL server? Try with this: `apt-get remove mysql-server`

Comment: There's a good post in frequently asked questions about [resolving unmet dependancies][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: @Lucio I updated my question

Comment: @CharlesGreen: I walked through that post step by step I still get the same error.

Comment: @CharlesGreen: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

credit to Ubuntu [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229585&p=13049690#post13049690)

Comment: Back then I thought I would give a chance for other answers
but OK now @A.B.